# How to export Matlab LUT to C code using Embedded Coder?

Tags: c, matlab

I have data from Simulink (Lookup tables generated from non-linear functions) 100x100 double array and my goal is to export it in the most efficient way from Matlab to C code so that I can implement it on a microcontroller and perform the interpolation.

I am interested in exporting the variables as opposed to functions which then I can easily use in the C files.

I have tried code generation with Matlab Coder however it is designed for converting Matlab function to C function which is not what I need.

Comment: Let Matlab write the array to a text file. Then write a small code generator that reads the text file and outputs something like `static double foo[] = {<contents of the text file>};`. Estimated number of lines of your C code generator: 30-40. Or generate the .c file directly from matlab, I don't know matlab, mut maybe that's even simpler.

Comment: Or just copy and paste it to some text processor and do some find/replace work manually.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't worked with Matlab for 10 years, so my answer may not be the best one.

As Jabberwocky already wrote, you might write a simple script that writes something like `int foo[] = { ...` to a file.

Simulink models have a property named `PostCodeGenCommand`. This property contains a list of Matlab commands and/or scripts to be executed after RTW code generation. And the value (the list of commands) is saved in the Simulink (.mdl) file. Details are described [on the MathWorks web site](https://de.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/customizing-post-code-generation-build-processing.html).

If you write the script writing the `int foo[] = ...` in Matlab (.m) instead of C, you may add this script to the `PostCodeGenCommand` property so it is executed everytime you generate code.